# CoordinatedShutdown timeout on Akka cluster application

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

We've an akka cluster application (sharding some actors). Sometimes, when we deploy and our application should be turned off we see some logs like that:

> Coordinated shutdown phase [cluster-sharding-shutdown-region] timed
>   out after 10000 milliseconds

This happens on the first deploy after more than 2 days since last deploy (on mondays for example). We ask the akka node to quit the cluster with the JMX helper and we have the following code too:

```
actorSystem.registerOnTermination {
  logger.error("Gracefully shutdown of node")
  System.exit(0)
}
```

So when this error happens, eventually node leaves the cluster (or at least it closes the JMX entry point to manage akka cluster) but process don't finish and the log "Gracefully shutdown of node" doesn't appear. So when this happen we need to shutdown the java process manually (we handle this with supervisor) and redeploy.

I know the timeout can be tunned through config but what are the implications of increasing this timeout? Why sometimes coordinated shutdown throws a timeout? What happens when coordinated shutdown timeout?

Any clue would be appreciated :D

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What happens after timeout? Quoting from [Akka documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/actors.html#coordinated-shutdown):

> If tasks are not completed within a configured timeout (see reference.conf) the next phase will be started anyway. It is possible to configure `recover=off` for a phase to abort the rest of the shutdown process if a task fails or is not completed within the timeout.

Why the shutdown may time out? Quite possible you have a deadlock somewhere. In that case, increasing the timeout wouldn't help. It may also very well be that you need more time for shutdown. Then, you must increase the timeout.

But more related to your problem, could be the following:

> By default, the JVM is not forcefully stopped (it will be stopped if all non-daemon threads have been terminated). To enable a hard System.exit as a final action you can configure:

```
akka.coordinated-shutdown.exit-jvm = on
```

So you can turn this on, which should solve the "shutdown the java process manually" step.

---

Nevertheless, the hard question is to find out why the shutdown times out in the first place. I guess with the above trick you can survive for some time, but you'd better spend some time to find the actual cause.

Answer (score 0):

We used to face this problem (One of the Co-ordinated shutdown phase timeout) for short lived application.

Use case where we faced this:

1. Application joins existing akka cluster
2. Does some work
3. Leaves the cluster

But at step 3, the status of member was still (Joining or WeaklyUp) and if you see task added for PhaseClusterLeave, it allows to remove member from cluster only if it's status is UP.

Snippet from ClusterDaemon.scala which is invoked on Running ClusterLeave phase :

```
def leaving(address: Address): Unit = {
  // only try to update if the node is available (in the member ring)
  if (latestGossip.members.exists(m ⇒ m.address == address && m.status == Up)) {
    val newMembers = latestGossip.members map { m ⇒ if (m.address == address) m.copy(status = Leaving) else m } // mark node as LEAVING
    val newGossip = latestGossip copy (members = newMembers)

    updateLatestGossip(newGossip)

    logInfo("Marked address [{}] as [{}]", address, Leaving)
    publishMembershipState()
    // immediate gossip to speed up the leaving process
    gossip()
  }
}
```

To solve this problem, we ended up writing our own CoordinatedShutdown which you can refer here [CswCoordinatedShutdown.scala](https://github.com/tmtsoftware/csw-prod/blob/master/csw-location/src/main/scala/csw/services/location/commons/CswCoordinatedShutdown.scala)